# Buff and debuff system for a tabletop RPG

Tags: java

i am making a RPG character sheet in Java, think of DnD and similar.

Ideally, I would want a class that does something similar to this:

```
Modifier modifier = new Modifier(bonusValue, listOfAffectedSkills);
modifier.giveTo(character);
modifier.removeFrom(character);

Modifier[] modifiers = character.getModifiers();
Modifier[] skillModifiers = character.getSkill().getModifiers();
```

However, i have no clue of how to pass the listOfAffectedSkills in a way I can implement the methods giveTo and removeFrom, specially since the character may have many skills of the same class and this should only affect a handful of them.

Answer (score 0):

Pepple should put a comment before downvoting ... I believe most of downvotes are because we don't know how your character class works, nor your modifier, nor your skill.

Personnally, I would rather have a `character.give(modifier)`, and `new Modifier(bonusValue,MODIFIER.name_of_skill)`. Skills should be dynamic (a `HashMap<String nameOfSkill,Skill s>` in a charcater, and you should have an inner map of bonuses modifier in the same way. Each time you get a skill modifier, you search if you have a bonus modifier with the same skill name, then return the skill modifier with its bonus modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you should implement listOfAffectedSkills as

```
List<ModifiableSkills>
```

(you can also have it support a "visitor pattern" which would make it more expandable, but for now what we have below will do).

So you would have:

Modifier:

```
public class Modifier {
  private int statBonus;
  private int saveBonus;
  private int armorBonus;

  // TODO: constructor, etc

  public int getStatBonus() {
    return statBonus;
  }

  public int getSaveBonus() {
    return saveBonus;
  }

  public int getArmorBonus() {
    return armorBonus;
  }
}
```

ModifiableSkills (interface to support the ability to modify with Modifier):

```
public interface ModifiableSkills {
    void modify(Modifier modifier);
}
```

Sample Skill that implements the ability to modify itself with Modifier, you can have other skill type which can be generically applied:

```
public class WarriorSkills implements ModifiableSkills {
    private int str;
    private int armor;
    private int save;

    void modify(Modifier modifier) {
        str += modifier.getStatBonus();
        armor += modifier.getArmorBonus();
        save += modifier.getSaveBonus();
    }
}
```

This should get you started.